# how it possible too generate a from it appear like popup

Tags: html

I can't solve this problem: If I click this button then it will appear like a pop up. How can I link to another html?

This is the out put html which is to be generated:

```
<html>
<body>
<fronm action="output.html" method="get">
first name:<input type="text" name:"first name"><br>
last name:<input type="text" name:"last name"><br>
moblieno:<input type="number" name:"mobileno"><br>
email:<input type ="email" name:"email"><br>
age:<input type="number" name:"age"><br>
school:<input type="text" name:"school"><br>
class:<input type="numeber/text" name:"class"><br>
<input type ="submit" value="submit">
</from>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>
    REGISTRATION FROM:
  </title>


  <style>
    p1.position_left {
      position: relative;
      top: 20px;
      down: 30px;
    }
    p2.position_right {
      position: relative;
      top: 45px;
      right: -65px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <table height: "200px" border: "3">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="background-color:#3152A5;" height="0" width="1350">
        <p1 style="color:white" class="pos_left" class="thicker"><b> <FONT SIZE=8 face="fantasy">registration</FONT></b>
        </p1>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <p style="font-style:italic" "color:black" if you are willing to fillup the registration from pls click below />
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p2>
          <from method="get" action="output.html">
            <button type="submit">continue</button>
          </from>

          <p>thanks for submission</p>
        </p2>
    </tr>
    </td>
</body>
</html>
```

The button then I will pop up the sign up a from. How can I make this possible?

Comment: Hi! I'm unsure what you're asking. Could you elaborate on that with a bit more text please?

Comment: hello jacob  the quwstion is that if u click on the button it generates a normal registration from . it would appear like pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the pure css pop up

```
    <style>
    .box {
      width: 40%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
      padding: 35px;
      border: 2px solid #fff;
      border-radius: 20px/50px;
      background-clip: padding-box;
      text-align: center;
    }


    .overlay {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      transition: opacity 500ms;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .overlay:target {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .popup {
      margin: 70px auto;
      padding: 20px;
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      width: 30%;
      position: relative;
      transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .popup h2 {
      margin-top: 0;
      color: #333;
      font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    .popup .close {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      right: 30px;
      transition: all 200ms;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #333;
    }
    .popup .close:hover {
      color: #06D85F;
    }
    .popup .content {
      max-height: 30%;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    </style>


<div class="box">
    <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Here i am</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content">
            Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```